# Can't establish connection between my VPS and itself

Tags: ubuntu, ip, vps, ping, connection

I have a VPS with two IP addresses: 74.117.158.92 and 74.117.159.204. If you ping them, you'll find they are both responding. I can also ping google.com etc. from either of them.

But I cannot ping one from the other. I can't ping localhost. I can't establish any TCP connections between server and client apps on the same box (though I can connect to those same servers from elsewhere).

I'm stumped. This change came suddenly after something happened to cause one of the venet0 interfaces to disappear, so most things are still configured as if connection between them were possible. For instance, my `iptables` configuration isn't causing this problem as it is the same one that worked great with everything before.

What might cause such a strange problem and what can I do?

Comment: paste "ip link show", "dmesg | grep venet0", what is in /proc/net/dev ? Also was the server ever rebooted? Can you show /etc/udev/rules.d/##-persistent-network-rules? And we'll go from there.

Comment: Ensure there's an iptables rule to accept incoming packets over the loopback interface. `iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` Will add it if not. Be sure to save the rule with `service iptables save` for your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in server firewall, Ip should not block in each other's firewall, check as below:

in iptables

> iptables -nL |grep IP

in csf

> grep  /etc/csf/*